# Changing locale at runtime in Swing

Tags: java, swing, internationalization

I would like to be able to change the locale in my Swing application at runtime and have all the text elements on the screen update themselves with localized text from a ResourceBundle of the new locale.

Can this be done without customizing swing components or creating UIDelegates for all components that handle rendering localized text?

If no, then what is a good solution I can consider implementing?

Comment: respondend here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810454/swing-internationalization-how-to-update-language-at-runtime/30960413#30960413

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. You have a method that is used to change app locale (and probably persist the new value) and another one to get localized strings.
2. Create an interface:

   ```
   interface LocaleChangeListener {
       void onLocaleChange();
   }
   ```

   Implement it by UI components that need to be able to change locale at runtime and set the new values in overrides `onLocaleChange()`.
3. Now, have a list of listeners that will be notified on locale change by the first method.

Comment: We decided to do something very similar to this.  Except we are going to use a couple system properties and reflection to attempt to refresh all the components on the screen when the event occurs.  The top level Jpanel is going to listen for local changes.

Answer (score 18):

use `ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME).getString(key);` to access the Strings.

when updating the Default Locale e.g. via `Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);`
clear the Resourcebundle cache: `ResourceBundle.clearCache();`

the next call of `ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME).getString(key);` should the return the localized String of the chosen Locale.

Comment: Though the other is pretty good and interesting, I think that´s the answer that should be really accepted

Comment: In my case I also had to add this
    JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.GERMAN);

Comment: Cannot see it working. Actually I don't know how can you make it work.

Comment: This doesn't update the text on the JComponents on Runtime

Answer (score 3):

You may want to save the language preference out, and then require a restart of the app for changes to take effect.

Then, you should be able to use `Locale.setDefault(Locale.<desired language>);` on startup, prior to rendering the GUI.  That should properly switch your locale, which will result in the desired .properties file(s) being loaded.

Comment: This is what we will do if we can't come up with something that fits into the timeline.  Thanks

Comment: The OP want something at runtime. Restart is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

What about, on changing locale, do a firePropertyChangeEvent("locale", "..."), then add propertyChangeListener() and register them, whereever labels and the like are to be updated?

Answer (score -1):

There's two obvious approaches I see:

Instead of getting a `String` from the `ResourceBundle`, get some kind of event-source `String` holder. `Document` would be the very heavy solution, but anything that can handle replacing an immutable value will do. Instead of just setting the text on a label, say, have a method that also sets up a listener. Note, this quite a "heavy" solution.

Alternatively, have a central repository of listeners that are fired on a locale change, that each then go back and re-execute the relevant part of the set up code (don't duplicate). For common cases where you have, say, a `JLabel` using a resource string literally, then you can combine these all into one listener with a `WeakHashMap<JLabel,String>`. Sometimes it works out better to avoid lots of little listeners.