# Change language ( localization) on-the-fly (runtime) on Java

Tags: java, localization

I have read a lot of similar questions, but dont seen elegant solving for my topic.

My way to change language is restart Application as showed below:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("de_DE"));
setVisible(false);

DlgMainApplication newApp = new DlgMainApplication();
newApp.setVisible(true);
dispose();
```

Is this correct way?
Its works, but only inside NetBeans. When i run stand-alone .jar file, language dont change.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but if you are using ResourceBundles with property files containing the translations, this answer here was the solution that worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5154408/2040852

In essence: set the new locale, clear the cache of ResourceBundle and reload the bundle.